# Jensen's inequality with ablosute values properties

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, jensen-inequality

How can i solve this |E(X ⁄Y)| ≤ E(|X|⁄Y) using the Jensen's inequality?
I know that this is convex but not differentiable. X/Y means X given Y, not X divide by Y
Does anyone now i link or a book? I only find the classic inequality, without the properties of ablosute value.

Comment: Differentiability is not needed, but convexity is.  For real rvs $Z$, J's inequality definitely gives you $|EZ|\le E|Z|$.  But what does your $|E(X/Y|$ mean?  The absolute value of the expectation of the ratio $X/Y$, or the abs value of the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$?  In once case you are safe, but in the other you are in danger.

Comment: @kimchilover sorry for the clarification. I edit it, is X given Y

Comment: Check out the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). It's not a super reference but makes clear that the absolute value function is OK with J.  The bit about conditioning is implicit in its discussion of the Rao-Blackwell theorem at the end of the article.

Comment: @kimchilover i've already seen this article and it wasn't very helpful but thanks for your help!!

Comment: How about [this one](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/conditional_expectation.pdf) ?

Comment: @kimchilover...Yes thats it....Thank you very much, i've looking for it all day!!!